# "Not enough resources available to fulfill the request" error in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In GCP, I'm trying to create a new notebook instance.

However, I got this error from all the zones that I tried:

> "tensorflow-2-4-20210214-113312: The zone 'projects/[PROJECT-ID]/zones/europe-west3-b' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later."

Comment: Have you tried a different zone?

Answer (score 0):

Even though the whole point of Cloud Computing is not to worry about the underlying infrastructure serving your application, at the end of the day there will be some servers with limited capacity and resources hosting your applications or supporting the underlying infrastructure of the product in question that you are using.

In the specific case of AI Platform Notebooks you can use the following command:

```
gcloud beta notebooks locations list
```

to get a list of the available locations and monitor the [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/release-notes) to check when new locations are added.  Try to create a new notebook in another location that do have available resources or wait for resources to be available on that particular zone.